# Парсинг картинок с сайта с использованием jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

стоит задача спарсить картинки новостей. Ранее тут уже помогли с парсингом заголовков новостей и самих новостей. Теперь необходимо прикрепить к заголовкам картинку. Пытался в потоке парсинга заголовка добавить картинку, ничего не вышло. Есть дума создать ещё 1 асинхронный класс и парсить картинки в него, а выводить уже привычным способом как показано в коде. Но есть несколько сомнений по этому поводу. Например то что картинки будут стоять криво. Так же на сайте картинки находятся в директории resource и как прикреплять ссылку к этой директории пока в голову не пришло. Выводится картинка думаю должна в imageview. 
Вот код:

```
public class news extends Activity {
Button back;
private TextView textView;
private ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(news.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    ParseTitle parseTitle = new ParseTitle();
    parseTitle.execute();
    try {
        final HashMap<String,String> hashMap = parseTitle.get();
        final ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Map.Entry entry : hashMap.entrySet()){
            arrayList.add(entry.getKey().toString());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(news.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ParseText parseText = new ParseText();
                parseText.execute(hashMap.get(arrayList.get(position)));
                try {
                    listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView.setText(parseText.get());
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


class ParseText extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String str = "";
        String str1 = "http://ktits.ru/";

        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(str1+strings[0]).get();
            Elements elements = document.select("div[class=text]").get(0).getElementsByTag("p");
            Log.i(str,"fgds");
            str = elements.first().ownText();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return str;

    }
}



class ParseTitle extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HashMap<String,String>>
{

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://ktits.ru").get();
            Elements elements = document.select("div[class=news]").get(0).getElementsByTag("a");
            for(Element element:elements) {
                hashMap.put(element.getElementsByClass("title").text(), element.attr("href"));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return hashMap;
    }
}
```

}

И html код:[image: html]

Прошу натолкнуть на путь истинный.

Comment: Изначально планировал вклинить это в класс parsetitle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Снова здравствуйте! К сожалению, я не знаком с andoid'ом от слова совсем, но нашел, что вам сможет [пригодится](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382887/parse-images-with-jsoup). Код должен быть примерно таким:

```
...
Map<String, BitMap> map = new HashMap<>();
try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://ktits.ru").get();
            Elements elements = document.select("div[class=news]").get(0).getElementsByTag("a");
            map = elements.stream()
                    .filter(element -> !element.classNames().contains("all-news"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(element -> element.getElementsByClass("title").text(),
                            element -> getBitMap("http://ktits.ru" + getImgUrl(element.getElementsByClass("img").first().attr("style")))));

    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

...

    private static String getImgUrl(String bckgImg){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'.*'");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(bckgImg);
        return matcher.find() ? matcher.group() : "";
    }

    private static BitMap getBitMap(String url) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream());
    }
```

Успехов!

Comment: А как по вашему, лучше в отдельный класс упаковать или "вклинить" в существующий поток?

Comment: @Domex, правильнее однозначно в отдельный класс, это основой подход для java'вы и программирования в целом, формировать логически законченные структурные единицы. Один класс - одна ответственность; как кто-то понимающий сказал.

Comment: Понял, учту. Спасибо за помощь.